# How to get original absolute path of file before saveAs() in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a form that takes in a file input. 
I want to get the absolute path of the file before saving it in `/web` folder because if I do `realpath()` after `saveAs()` it gives me the absolute path of `/web` folder not the original directory. If I do it before, it doesn't return anything. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If youre using `UploadedFile`:

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
echo $model->file->tempName; // this is temp file path before saving
```

It's accessible before calling `saveAs()` method, because `saveAs()` will delete temporary file after saving it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've tried this and it gives me the yii2's tmp folder directory. Not the directory from where the file came.

Comment: You want directory from where user uploaded his own file?

Comment: As far as i know - no.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info though. Have an upvote. Been helpful.